# Explain how did I get the answer correctly: Given vectors v defined by basis b1, b2, b3...

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not sure how I've got the correct answer, but I'll share my rationale and hope the community can help me:

Given

$v=\begin{bmatrix} -4  \\-3  \\8 \end{bmatrix}$,$b_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1  \\2  \\3 \end{bmatrix}$,$b_2=\begin{bmatrix} -2  \\1  \\0 \end{bmatrix}$,$b_3=\begin{bmatrix} -3  \\-6  \\5 \end{bmatrix}$

All written in the standard basis, what is $v$ in the basis defined by $b_1$, $b_2$ and $b_3$? It's given that $b_1$, $b_2$ and $b_3$ are all pairwise orthogonal to each other.

To get the correct answer I simply added $b_1$ + $b_2$ + $b_3$ and noticed it was equal to $v$. Then I was presented with 4 possible answers. 3 of them with different elements (eg: <0,0,1>).

There was one option $\begin{bmatrix} 1  \\1  \\1 \end{bmatrix}$ but no option$\begin{bmatrix} 0  \\0  \\0 \end{bmatrix}$ so I assumed that could only be the answer since $(b_1 + b_2 + b_3 )=v=TRUE$ and if $TRUE$ then all elements should be 1, because, well...$0=FALSE, 1=TRUE$. Seriously...that was how I tackled the problem...

Could you please help me understand what's the underlying rationale in here? Vector projection of $v$ onto $b_1$ + $b_2$ + $b_3$? If so, would the formula be $\frac{v(b_1 + b_2 + b_3)}{|b_1 + b_2 + b_3|^2}$ ? Of course this results in $1$. So...

...Why am I summing $b_1 + b_2 + b_3$? Is this to create a single vector to serve as the basis for $v$? Is it okay to say it would be the sort-of new "x-axis" for v?

...What do I do with that $1$ what I've got as the result of the projection?

...Why did this work and I've got the right answer?

I studied this, but am not yet sure if I understand what I did.

Thanks!

Comment: Since $b_1,b_2,b_3$ is a basis, every vector, in particular this $v$, can be uniquely written as $xb_1+yb_2+zb_3$ for some scalars $x,y,z$, which are just the coordinates you're looking for. Once you verified that $b_1+b_2+b_3=v$, by uniqueness we must have $x=y=z=1$, and you're done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard basis is $a_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1  \\0  \\0 \end{bmatrix}$, $a_2=\begin{bmatrix} 0  \\1  \\0 \end{bmatrix}$, $a_3=\begin{bmatrix} 0  \\0  \\1 \end{bmatrix}$. To say that $v=\begin{bmatrix} -4  \\-3  \\8 \end{bmatrix}$ in this basis is just shorthand for $v = -4a_1 + -3a_2 +8a_3$. Similarly, if you find that $v = 1b_1 + 1b_2 + 1b_3$, this can be shorthanded as $\begin{bmatrix} 1  \\1  \\1 \end{bmatrix}$ in that basis.

Comment: Got it. Second part is pretty clear. As for the first part I understand we're basically representing each vector on its unit length form? So $b1$, in the standard basis, would be $1a_1$ $2a_2$ $3a_3$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "representing each vector on its unit length form." Your latter statement is correct (but missing the plus signs), although to say that it's "in the standard basis" is somewhat redundant: that just means that you chose to write it as a sum of only $a_1, a_2$, and $a_3$ (which we can already see). Saying that a column vector is "in" a particular basis, on the other hand, is critical, since it's telling you _which_ basis vectors it is a weighted sum of.

Comment: I meant unit basis which is the same as standard basis. I read it again and it's pretty clear now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You need to take every projection separate :

$\frac{(1)}{|1|2} = 1$

$\frac{(2)}{|2|2} = 1$

$\frac{(3)}{|3|2} = 1$

so the v vector by basis b is :  $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1  \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$